# Show a percent as a stand-a-lone on Power BI dashboard

Tags: standalone, powerbi

I want to get the percentage from two columns (ColumnA and ColumnB) and show it up on my Power BI dashboard as a stand a lone card.

Do I have to make a calculated Column first? Then how do I get this to show up just as a percentage sign (45%) on the Power BI Dashboard?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It would better if you create calculated column within PowerBI as it will provide more flexibility in terms of data manipulation. More information about calculated column is [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns/) and [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/guided-learning/powerbi-learning-2-3-create-calculated-columns/)